# Angular 4 Reset status form

Tags: forms, angular

I have a modal with a form, and some required fields.
When I open the modal I correctly see the fields empty, if I write something in the field required and then I cancel the words writed I correctly see the field as invalid.
The problem is that if I close and reopen the modal I want to see the empty fields like if it's the first time I open it but for some reason I see the previous invalid status also if I reset the form.
This is my modal after I close it, it seems that the status never be resetted:
[image]

```
                              <form #modelForm="ngForm">
                                    <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="checkpoint">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                                <label class="control-label">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.labels.name'
                                                    | translate }}<span class="star">*</span>
                                                </label> <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required
                                                    [(ngModel)]="checkpoint.name" #name="ngModel" /><small
                                                    [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="text-danger">
                                                    {{'checkpoint.table.validations.required' | translate }}</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                                <label class="control-label">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.labels.passStockAlert'
                                                    | translate }}</label> <input pattern="[0-9]*"
                                                    class="form-control" name="passStockAlert"
                                                    id="passStockAlert"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="checkpoint.passStockAlert"
                                                    #checkPoint="ngModel" /><small
                                                    [hidden]="checkPoint.valid || checkPoint.pristine"
                                                    class="text-danger">
                                                    {{'checkpoint.table.validations.invalid' | translate }}</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="category form-category">
                                                <span class="star">*</span> {{ 'form.requiredfields' |
                                                translate }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-round"
                                            (click)="save();resetForm(modelForm)" data-dismiss="modal"
                                            [disabled]="modelForm.form.invalid || modelForm.form.pristine"
                                            label="Save">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.save' |
                                            translate }}</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-round"
                                            (click)="resetForm(modelForm)" data-dismiss="modal">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.close' |
                                            translate }}</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

And this is my reset form method:

```
  resetForm(myForm: NgForm) {
    myForm.form.reset();
  }
```

Comment: Please format your code. it's unreadable

Comment: Use myForm.reset(); instead of myForm.form.reset();

Comment: @Chandru it doesn't change

Comment: @yurzui updated

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented this:

**my-component.html**

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="resetFormFlags(myForm)" #myForm="ngForm">
      <h4> title </h4>
      <button type="submit"> btnText</button>
  </form>
```

**my-component.ts**

```
resetFormFlags(myForm: any) {
   myForm.reset();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Does it change if you use submit and I don't?

Comment: I don´t think so, Actually I think that your problem is in myForm.form.reset(); try to change to  myForm.reset();

Comment: Doesn't change, same result

Comment: I made a plunker showing the functionality:

https://plnkr.co/edit/d7GNQ5HgWkQZcnEhyTGl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below code :

```
<form name="modelForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="resetForm(modelForm)" #modelForm="ngForm">
    <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="checkpoint">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.labels.name'
                    | translate }}<span class="star">*</span>
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required [(ngModel)]="checkpoint.name" />
                <small [hidden]="!(modelForm.controls.name?.dirty && modelForm.controls.name?.invalid)" class="text-danger">
                    {{'checkpoint.table.validations.required' | translate }}
                </small>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="modelForm.form.invalid" type="submit">{{'checkpoint.table.dialog.save' | translate }}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-white" type="button" (click)="resetForm(modelForm)"> {{'checkpoint.table.dialog.close' | translate }}</button>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**componen.ts**

```
resetForm(editForm: NgForm) {
    editForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: i did't add #name="ngModel" in my answer it will be working for me. try this answer